# From general ramification theory to ramification indexes of morphisms of elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, dedekind-domain, ramification

*The reference for what I'll say here is Silverman's *The arithmetic of elliptic curves*, ch. 2, § 2.*

Let $C_1, C_2$ be two elliptic curves, $\Phi : C_1 \to C_2$ a non trivial morphism of algebraic projective curves and $P\in C_1$ a point. From that, Silverman *defines* the **index of ramification of $\Phi$ at $P$** and denotes $e_\Phi(P)$ to be $$e_\Phi(P) := \mathrm{ord}_P(\Phi^* t_{\Phi(P)}),$$ where $t_{\Phi(P)}\in K(C_2)$ is a uniformiser at $\Phi(P)$.

I have two problems: the first is to connect this definition of the ramification index to the general theory of ramification in Dedekind rings; the second is to derive the following identity from the general theory: for all point $Q\in C_2$, the equality $\star$ $$\sum_{P\in \Phi^{-1}(Q)} e_\Phi(P) = \deg(\Phi)$$ holds. I think I solved the first problem but not the second and I get contradictive results.

#### First problem

Let $$A = \Phi^* K[C_2]_{\Phi(P)}.$$ Since $K[C_2]_{\Phi(P)}$ is Dedekind, $A$ is Dedekind as well since $\Phi^*$ is an injective ring homomorphism and is therefore a ring isomorphism on its image. Note that since $K[C_2]_{\Phi(P)}$ is a local ring with only one maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_{\Phi(P)}$, the ring $A$ is local as well with only maximal ideal $\Phi^* \mathfrak{m}_{\Phi(P)}$. Since $A$ is a Dedekind ring, its maximal ideal is also its only prime ideal.

Now let $$B = K[C_1]_P.$$ This ring is a Dedekind local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}_P$. We have an inclusion $$A\subset B.$$ Indeed, if $x\in K[C_2]_{\Phi(P)}$ is well defined at $\Phi(P)$, then $\Phi^* x := x\circ \Phi$ is automatically well defined at $P$.

Therefore $A\subset B$ is a tower of Dedekind rings and the so-called index of ramification of $\Phi$ at $P$ can be seen as the index of ramification (in the sense of the ramification theory in Dedekind rings) of the prime ideal $\mathfrak{m}_P$ over $A$. Indeed, the Dedekind rings $A$ and $B$ both only have one prime ideal, therefore the decomposition of $\Phi^*\mathfrak{m}_{\Phi(P)}$ must be of the form $\mathfrak{m}_P^e$ for some integer $e$.

#### Second problem

Now let's try to derive the formula $\star$ for a given point $Q\in C_2$. A well-known equality from ramification theory in Dedekind rings is that if $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal in $A$, then $$\sum_{\mathfrak{P}|\mathfrak{p}} e_{\mathfrak{P}/\mathfrak{p}} f_{\mathfrak{P}/\mathfrak{p}} = [\mathrm{Frac}(B) : \mathrm{Frac}(A)],$$ where $e_{\mathfrak{P}/\mathfrak{p}}$ is the ramification index of $\mathfrak{P}$ over $\mathfrak{p}$ and $f_{\mathfrak{P}/\mathfrak{p}}$ is the residual degree. First, here we have $[\mathrm{Frac}(B) : \mathrm{Frac}(A)] = \mathrm{deg}(\Phi)$. Second, with that being said and what I wrote in the previous section, necessarily $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{m}_{\Phi(P)}$, $\mathfrak{P} = \mathfrak{m}_P$ and the equality yields $$e_\Phi(P)\cdot f_{\mathfrak{m}_{\Phi(P)}/\mathfrak{m}_P} = \mathrm{deg}(\Phi),$$ which contradicts the equality $\star$ given by Silverman.

Could you explain what I did wrong? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You forgot that in that part of Silverman's book he is working with elliptic curves over an *algebraically closed* field, so all the residue fields are algebraically closed and thus $f = 1$!  If you look in any treatment of Riemann surfaces or of  algebraic geometry over $\mathbf C$, you'll see lots of $e$'s all over the place but no $f$'s because all the $f$'s are $1$. You don't notice residue fields changing classically (over $\mathbf C$) because they are all the same field.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did not know this property for residual degrees of algebraic closed fields! But I still do not see how this gives $\star$. With what you said and my (probably wrong) reasoning, for any $P\in \Phi^{-1}(\{Q\})$ we'd have $e_\Phi(P) = \mathrm{deg}(\Phi)$. But Silverman states that the **sum** verifies $\sum_{p\in \Phi^{-1}(\{Q\})}e_\Phi(P) = \mathrm{deg}(\Phi)$. Contradiction (unless $\mathrm{Card}(\Phi^{-1}(\{Q\})$ is always $1$ but this is obviously not true).

Comment: I think you implicitly knew this property of residue fields when they are algebraically closed: if a field is algebraically closed and another field is a finite extension of it then the field degree has to be $1$. So $f = 1$ since residue field extensions are finite extensions (for residue fields of Dedekind domains in a finite extension of their fraction fields) and therefore when the bottom residue field is algebraically closed, the top residue field has to be the same field.

Comment: It is false that $B$ has one nonzero prime ideal when $A$ has one nonzero prime ideal. Maybe $B$ does, maybe $B$ doesn't. In general it doesn't. You can see this already for $A = \mathbf Z_{(p)}$ (localization of $\mathbf Z$ at a prime $p$) and $B$ being the integral closure of $A$ in $\mathbf Q(i)$. If $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ then there are two primes in $B$ lying over $p\mathbf Z$.

Comment: The typically multiple (but finitely many) prime ideals in $B$ lying over the single prime in $A$ is where you get a sum.

Comment: You're right for the algebraic fields!
If I am not mistaken, $B$ does have one *and only one* prime ideal: it is a local ring (see Silverman, beginning of ch. 2) therefore it has one and only one maximal ideal; it is also a Dedekind ring therefore its prime ideals are its maximal ideals. Same goes for $A$.

Comment: Okay, I reread the post to see what your notation means. The ring $B$, the local ring at $P$, has one maximal ideal but is *not* the integral closure of $A$ in ${\rm Frac}(B)$. Consider the local ring $B = \mathbf Z[i]_{(1+2i)}$ in $\mathbf Q(i)$ and $A = B \cap \mathbf Q = \mathbf Z_{(5)}$. Here $B$ is not the integral closure of $A$ in ${\rm Frac}(B) = \mathbf Q(i)$: it is too big (e.g., it contains $1/(1-2i)$). The identity $\sum e_if_i = \deg(L/K)$ requires integral closures. In $\mathbf Q(i)$, the integral closure of $\mathbf Z_{(5)}$ is $\mathbf Z[i]_{(1+2i)} \cap \mathbf Z[i]_{(1-2i)}$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, I was therefore not considering the right rings. I will start again. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go to local rings. You can work just with global fields. See my answer at [order of kernel of surjection between curves is equal to separate degree](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914468/order-of-kernel-of-surjection-between-curves-is-equal-to-separate-degree/3915164#3915164) for details.